# I receive either Failed unmounting cd or dev/loop2: can’t open devblock. I’ve tried everything I can find online but nothing has worked

Tags: server, software-installation

I need to install Ubuntu server on virtual box for class. I followed instructions exactly but when I try to install I get either
Failed UNMOUNTING /cdrom
DEV/loop2: can’t open blockdev

What can I do to complete install?

Comment: 1) Isn't this what you are paying your instructor for? 2) Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1279589/edit): Add a link to the instructions that you are following. Make clear to us exactly which step you are seeking help with.

Comment: I've exactly replicated this problem on real hardware (Dell Precision TR5400) today - no VirtualBox.  Was there ever a resolution?